# Booyer y Moore con Double linked list

Tags: java

Hola ya tengo creada mi clase y métodos para tener una double Linked Pero ahora tengo que hacer el algoritmo Booyer y Moore para poder leer esos datos y me diga la posición de las coincidencias que encontro, este es mi main

```
  Public static void main(String[] args)
  ListaDoble ld=new ListaDoble();
  ld.InsertarInicio("Juan");
  ld.InsertarInicio("Felipe");
  ld.InsertarInicio("Margarita");
  ld.InsertarFin("Mario");
  ld.InsertarFin("Zacarias");

ld.MostrarAdelante();//Muestra los nombres de las listas
```

Comment: Cual es la duda?